# How to call a .html.erb file inside another .html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a structure which looks like below where-in I need to call a .html.erb file in another.

main_layout.html.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        how to call the sub_layout here
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

sub_layout.html.erb

```
<div>
  <p> This is the nested layout to be rendered inside main_layout </p>
</div>
```

I tried with the below options.

<%= render sub_layout.html.erb %> 
<%= ERB.new(open("sub_layout.html.erb").read).result(binding) %>

Both of the above options is not working. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# main_layout.html.erb
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <%= render 'sub_layout' %>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will look for a file `_sub_layout.html.erb` in the same folder as `main_layout.html.erb`

If the `_sub_layout.html.erb` is not in the same folder as `main_layouts.html.erb` you need to define the complete path `<%= render 'your/path/to/sub_layout' %>`

Comment: i tried this. This is not working. it says undefined method `render'

Comment: Can you add the complete error to your question?

Comment: undefined method `render' for #<Reports::Model Name> .. this is the only error I have in console

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rename your file from "sub_layout.html.erb" to "_sub_layout.html.erb" and run it.